# How to pass one part of url string to variable in view

Tags: python, django

I dont know how to pass one part of my url address(date) to variable in view.
The url address looks almost like: `xxxx/user/date` e.g. `www.dat/kowalski/20160101`
and I would like to pass the date `20160101` to variable in views. How to do it? I am new in python and Django.

I created url pattern in urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    .....
    url(r'^tmp/(?P<username>[a-z0-9]+)/(\d{8})/$', views.DateStats.as_view(), name='datestats'),)
```

and very basic views but what should I do to save date to variable??

Answer (score 3):

You do the same as you do with the username: give the capturing group a name.

```
r'^tmp/(?P<username>[a-z0-9]+)/(?P<date>\d{8})/$'
```

Comment: I don't understand. Give me part of code to save the date into variable in views.py

Comment: This is part of code in urls.py file but I have to use and pass date in views.py file. I got there simply function. How to use <date> in views.py ?

Comment: I can't really see what you're not understanding here. Do you have a view? What parameters does it take now? Have you done the tutorial, where all this is fully explained?

Comment: Yes, I have the view. It takes def get(self, request, username):

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get url parameters in the views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class DateStats(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        date = self.kwargs.get('date')
        # do something with date
```